# How do Google apps on iOS know my Google account?

Tags: ios, privacy

Say I currently have no apps from Google on my iPhone. I am pretty sure that is the case, because I go to the app store, search for "Google LLC" (the developer of Google's apps), and scroll through all the apps by this developer and none is installed. Then I install Google Maps, go to saved places, and it shows a bunch of things I had saved in the past. I delete maps, I install Chrome, and it asks me whether I want to sign in with xxx@gmail.com (my account). How is this possible??? If they were using `identifierForVendor`, that would get reset when all apps from that developer are deleted, as is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor). PS, no, I am not trying to replicate this creepy behavior in my own app, I am just bothered by this possibility. So from that perspective this question is *maybe* more suitable for superuser.com, but still, it is pretty much a programming question, and I am looking for an answer that would explain how one would achieve this. But also what we, as privacy-conscious users, can do to limit such behavior.

Comment: check this article: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps

Comment: Keychain is disabled on my iPhone.